# How to map Columns in Elasticsearch with Postman (illegal argument exception)

Tags: json, elasticsearch, postman

I'm learning Elasticsearch and Postman. I've set up Elasticsearch and it's up and running at my localhost:9200. I'm following the tutorial on Elasticsearch with Postman.

[image]

**I put the object in the body as JSON**
[image]

And I'm getting the following error.

[image]

Comment: you have to put them into the body, chosing JSON as contenttype. Also you have to make sure it is valid json.

Comment: @aHochstein  thanks~  I did both, and I got this error message. Could you take a look? I will edit my question

Comment: have a look at your apostrophes they look kinda strange in your example json, it should look like this: "property" : "value"

Comment: @aHochstein I switched that as well.

Comment: you are reaching your elasticsearch now, what u see is an server error. Have a look at the tutorial :)

Comment: @aHochstein  hmmm /_cat/indices or /team/_close , /team/_open still works.  thank you ~ I"ll take a look closely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type "string" is not used anymore, so I changed that to "text"

**`"type": "text"` This seems to work. When I invoke a GET request `localhost:9200/team/_mapping` I get the results fine.**

However, it says

> types are being removed from Elasticsearch in 7.0, the mappings element will no longer return the type name as a top-level key by default.

I am really new,(started to learn elasticsearch today) so I do not know in detail.

Comment: yes exactly concerning the type warning, it refers to type `member` that you are specifying in you URL. From what I've seen the recommended way to provide explicit mapping is by doing `PUT` to `localhost:9200/team` with a json body `{"mappings":{ "properties":{ "id": {"type":"text"}, [...] }}`

Comment: @A.J Alhorr I think you are right. Thank you for your clarification. I need to review the stuff agian. over the weekend, I forgot most of it again. lol